# An inverse cosine problem 2

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

solve the equation $\cos{z}=\sqrt{2}$ for z

i am making a mistake somewhere, here is my attempt
$$z=-i\log({\sqrt{2}+i(1-2)^{1/2})}$$$$z=-i\log(\sqrt{2}-1)$$$$z=-i[\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)+i(2n\pi)]$$$$z=2n\pi + -i\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)$$

Comment: Set $x+iy$ where $x,y$ are real and expand cosine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite following you in your work. Here is a set up: With $cos^2z+sin^2z=1$ we find $sinz=\pm{i}$. Now use identity $e^{iz}=cosz+isinz$ with the given info of $cosz$ and $sinz$. One solution would be $e^{iz}=\sqrt{2}+1$ from which you can take the $ln$ to find $iz=ln(\sqrt{2}+1)$ and that you can solve for $z$ by multiplying both sides by $-i$. Can you find the other solution? Also beware of the multiplicities.

Comment: my book defines $$arccos(z)=-i\log(z+i\sqrt{1-z^{2}})$$

Comment: But is that formula helpful in this question? You still need $z$. I usually use Euler's identity for these problems. Goes very easy

Comment: This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166562/solve-sinz-2?rq=1

Comment: This is perhaps better. Sine goes same way of course: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945602/finding-z-in-mathbb-c-with-sin-z-2/1945713#1945713

Comment: My professor has only solved these types of problems using the definition i posted, but i do see how yours makes sense. do you see any errors with my original post?

Comment: Well, $
(1-2)^\frac{1}{2}$ is essentially $\sqrt{-1}$ but in this context, that ought to be $i$ and $-i$. yielding two solutions. You only got one

Comment: then would the full solution be $-i\ln(\sqrt{2} \pm 1)$

Comment: I think that's what I also would get from my approach (multiplicities too, complex cosine is still periodic)

Comment: ok thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

$$ \cos(x+iy) = \cos x\cosh y - i\sin x\sinh y$$

so we have $$ \cos x \cosh y = \sqrt{2} \\ \sin x \sinh y = 0$$

If $\sinh y = 0$ then $\cosh y = 1$ and $\cos x = \sqrt{2}$ which yields no solution, so $\sin x = 0$

Furthermore, $\cosh y \ge 0$, so $\cos x \ge 0$ or $\cos x = 1$ which means $x = 2n\pi$

This leaves $\cosh y = \sqrt{2}$ or $y = \pm\ln (\sqrt{2} + 1)$, so the solution is

$$ z = 2n\pi \pm i \ln (\sqrt{2} + 1) $$

Comment: You might at least note that your $ z = 2n\pi \pm i \ln (\sqrt{2} + 1) $ is equivalent to the OP's $ z = 2n\pi \pm i \ln (\sqrt{2} - 1) $...

Comment: I think OP meant to write $2n\pi - i\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)$ which would make an incomplete answer.

Comment: Even if it was supposed to be $\pm$, there's no way they would have arrived at both signs, given the work before it.

Comment: Yes the question is a mess, but it does write $+-$. And anyway, this is not my main point here, which is that you ought to describe precisely the relationship of your solution with what the OP did (or did not do).

Comment: Fair enough. I din't do that when I first wrote the answer, because I believed OP's wasn't correct, so it wouldn't matter. My answer wasn't picked anyway. Thanks for pointing it out in the comments so I don't have to.